# hardinfo cpu processor information

Tags: cpu-architecture

I have run hardinfo and generated a report and I am puzzled to see the processors. The report says that the computer has 4 i3 processors, but at the same time 3 of the 4 show to be running at 800 MHz ( atleast thats what I understand with the last column )

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz800.00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz2100.00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz800.00MHz
Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2310M CPU @ 2.10GHz800.00MHz
```

I dont understand why do I have 800 MHz at 3 places? Can anyone answer?

Edit: Benchmark result

```
Benchmarks
CPU Blowfish
CPU Blowfish
This Machine 800 MHz 5.701
Intel(R) Celeron(R) M processor 1.50GHz(null) 26.1876862
PowerPC 740/750 (280.00MHz)(null) 172.816713⁠⁠⁠⁠
```

Comment: To me this seems quite normal. Intel speedstep regulates the clock-speeds and lowers them to save power. If you run a benchmark or something similar, you should see that the clock speeds are all 2100 MHz. You can play a videogame, or download prime95: http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/prime95-download.html )

Comment: It’s Hyper-Threading and probably a display error, seeing how there are only two phyisical cores involved. But perhaps someone else can offer more insight.

Comment: I agree with Daniel, there must be a mistake there anyway. I guess that one core is running on 800 MHz and one on 2100 MHz. This essentially means one is idle and one is not. If you install HWMonitor you can monitor the clock speed in realtime. This will help you see whether this is the constant state of your processor, or you only sometimes have this situation. If this gives you similar results, let us know. http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html. (what I meant before is to run a benchmark while measuring the clock-speed, as you can do for instance with HWMonitor)

Comment: I have added the Blowfish benchmark. From where did you get the information that there are only two physical cores involved?

Comment: An i3-2310m has only two physical cores. It uses an intel technology called Hyper-threading. This essentially breaks up one core into two "virtual cores". This has some smart ideas that give you a performance advantage in some situations. Most computer programs don't see the difference between real physical cores and these virtual cores, therefore you see four cores, whereas you really have only two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments above ( Thanks to @ BramMooij ) , I checked it and its correct that Intel speedstep regulates the clock-speeds and lowers them to save power. 
To know the current clock speed, I used

```
watch -d "cat /cpu/procinfo | grep -i MHz"
```

on one window. On an another terminal window, to know the current CPU load I ran

```
htop
```

and on the third window mprime downloaded from http://www.mersenne.org/download/#download.

```
./mprime
```

with the option Options/Benchmark. The CPU Clock speed varied between 800 and 2100 MHz. This also answers my question, about the various clock speeds I got when I ran the Blowfish benchmark with

```
hardinfo
```